# Devise/Warden custom single-sign-on strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

I want my SSO custom strategy to be the only strategy that devise uses.  I'm doing this by:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :my_sso_strategy
end
```

This is where I get stuck.  I want to invoke the strategy, and I thought this would be done for me by:

```
app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
```

But, it doesn't look like my strategy gets invoked.

I took away the :authenticatable / :database_authenticatable from the devise declaration in my User model thinking that may be causing the problem.
After making the sign-in/out routes manually (because :authenticatable makes them), I get an AbstractController::ActionNotFound error.

At this point I'm at a loss how to continue.

My views should be setup correctly to auto-submit my credentials I get from the SSO application (it worked in authlogic)

Has anyone done something similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure unless you share how you coded the strategy. The simple answer is that you need a valid? method defined to specify when to use the strategy. Since you only want to use one strategy then I would expect your valid method to be like this..

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:my_sso_strategy) do 
  def valid?
    true
  end 

  def authenticate!
   #do authentication
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually if you don't define the valid? Method it will default to true and always execute the authenticate! method for that strategy. I'm still reading and learning about the interaction between devise and warden as I'm working something very similar...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen others use the ":user" scope and noticed you did not have it in your excerpt.  Perhaps that is causing the original error.

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :fb_database_authenticatable
end
```